# How do you increment a click counter on a button and make the button perform its original action?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to count how many times I click a button on a page and I can even do it via the Firefox console. My counter is incremented, but the button does not perform the original action. My code is as follows:

```
var button = document.getElementById("buttonid"),
  count = 0;
button.onclick = function() {
  count += 1;
  console.log(count);
};
```

Comment: What's the "original action"?

Comment: I guess you original action was depends on click but here you've replaced entire function with counter logic

Comment: What I meant by the original action is the action that the button was programmed to do, send a form, for example. I told a button in a generic way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `addEventListener` you can maintain multiple listeners without the possibility of overwriting previous ones.

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  count += 1;
  console.log(count);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would do that this is the code you should use:

```js
var clickCount = 0;
function myFunction() {
clickCount += 1;
// code it was supposed to do goes here
}
```